# How to iterate through all the files/folders in a folder

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm making a script to go through a folder renaming all the files and folders in it to VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, etc.. where VAR is a user specified variable. I wrongly assumed this would be simple.

All I need to know is how to make a 'for' loop iterate through all the items inside a certain folder, so how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Recursively or one level?

Comment: @Grzegorz what do you mean :P

Comment: In the given folder or also subfolders (subdirectories?) I am asking because you can use either '*' or the `find` command.

Comment: @Grzegorz only the given folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. You need to do your own script and pass arguments. Below is only procedure that works for your arguments. All arguments checking is left for you.

```
prefix=AAA
i=1
for f in * ; do
   mv $f $prefix$i
   ((i++))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find` to list all the files and directories to give a command along the lines of:-

```
find TargetDir|sort -r|while f="`line`"; do ((n=$n+1)); mv "$f" "${f%/*}/$VAR$n"; done
```

The reverse `sort` makes sure that files are renamed before the directories in their paths are renamed.

Comment: `find` is recursive. Extra options `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` are needed to confine traverse depth.

Comment: @AbelCheung - The questioner implies that he wants to rename through all subdirectories. I would not have suggested `find` for a single-level search.

Comment: Check out the comments immediately below original question.

Comment: @AbelCheung - OK. That comment wasn't there when I started to write my answer.